# why the for loop array is not working in bash language?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I need to run this code but the code did not accept the for loop it seems to the problem in array not equal to 0 is not working in shell script.

```
for((i=0; i<=nf && ff[i]!=0; i++))
do
   echo "    $i    ${f[i]}    ${ff[i]}    ${b[ff[i]]}   ${frag[i]}"
done
```

How to do this loop in bash that can run and show the output?***

Comment: Please post a reproducible example. Your code misses the initialization of the variables and it is therefore hard to discuss it. For the safe side, also post the version of your bash (By doing a `echo $BASH_VERSION` just before entering the loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop seems to work fine:

```
nf=3
ff=(1 2 3)
b=("a" "b" "c" "d")
frag=("?" "!" "%")

for((i=0; i<=nf && ff[i]!=0; i++))
do
  echo "    $i    ${f[i]}    ${ff[i]}    ${b[ff[i]]}   ${frag[i]}"
done
#>    0        1    b   ?
#>    1        2    c   !
#>    2        3    d   %
```

What's the problem you are having? What output do you get? Are you sure your arrays/variables are set properly? Are you sure you are using bash (i.e. not sh)?

Comment: there is no output showing when i run this loop , but without the array condition in the loop its show the output with no exact result. Is there any other way to write this array condition in the this loop?

Comment: Hi @hibluner - you accepted this answer - did you figure out the problem?